# Scons: how to check file before compilation with commands which doesn't product any output file?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, clang, scons

I work with project in which every object files is being built 3 times:

1. With newest g++ with lots of flags in order to find every possible errors and warnings
2. With clang in order to do as above and check style.
3. With g++ compatible with 3rdpart libraries (no newer version, but entire product is based of the libraries)
   It works that way: if any object file should be recompiled: the steps 1, if success then 2, if success then 3 is being done. It is done with makefile, but I'm planning to use scons to do its. The problem is that in current solution object file from 1 and 2 is being saved into /dev/null.

I've tried something line this:
3 files in the same directory: hello.cc, Sconstruct, Sconscript

SConstruct

```
#!python

warningFlags = ' -Wall -Wextra -Werror' # and many more

env = Environment(CXX = 'g++-4.8', parse_flags = warningFlags, CPPPATH = '.')

builtObjects = env.SConscript('SConscript', variant_dir='built', duplicate=0, exports='env')

env.Program(target = 'hello', source = builtObjects)
```

SConscript

```
#!python

Import('env')

builtObjects = env.Object(source = 'hello.cc')
checkWithClang = env.Command('/dev/null', builtObjects, 'clang -o $TARGET -Wall -Werror')
env.Depends(checkWithClang, builtObjects)

Return('builtObjects')
```

The output from scons is:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: built
g++-4.8 -o built/hello.o -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Ibuilt -I. hello.cc
g++-4.8 -o hello built/hello.o
scons: done building targets.
```

EDIT:
Is it possible to somehow check in scons:
if object file should be rebuilt?
Pseudo code:

```
src = 'hello.cc'
if shouldObjectFileBeRebuilt(src):
    checkWithClang = env.Command('/dev/null', builtObjects, 'clang -o $TARGET -Wall -Werror')
    builtObjects = env.Object(source = src)
    env.Depends(checkWithClang, builtObjects)
```

Comment: Is your real environment a single directory? Or is it actually top level dir with many subdirs of source code where you want to do the above?

Comment: @bdbaddog Real environment has many subdirs of source code, so when I try: env.Command('/dev/null' ... for multiple objects it it error from scons

Answer (score 1):

try

```
src = "hello.cc"
builtObjects = env.Object(source = src)
checkWithClang = env.Command('/dev/null', src, 'clang -o $TARGET -Wall -Werror')
env.Depends(builtObjects, checkWithClang)
```

1. buildobjects represent '.o' files, so you should put '.c' files to clang
2. you want buildObjects to be built after clang objects - change the order

Still - building into `/dev/null` will probably break dependency tree, you might consider something like:

```
checkWithClang = env.Object(source = src, CC="clang", OBJPREFIX="clang-")
```

this will build all .c files with clang and store extra .o files, allowing scons to rebuild only what is necessarry